# control thinkpad power led to display charging status

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, battery, thinkpad

Older ThinkPads had a row of dedicated LEDs from which one could tell at a glance status of various subsystems (hdd access, wifi, external power, etc).

I now have a refurbished X1 Carbon 6th Gen which has no dedicated indicator row, just the power button that is lit when the machine is on.

---

I have recently started having problems with its USB-C charging connection being unreliable. If I lock the screen and go away for a while I often come back to find the battery has discharged and the machine has shut itself down. Wiggling the connector makes charging resume.

I am using Xubuntu with the Xfce panel set to auto-minimise.

Currently, the only way I can tell if the connector is passing charge is:

- spot the popup when it disconnects (no use if I am away from keyboard)
- open the panel and check the power indicator before I lock the screen (easy to forget)

A permanently-visible indicator of charging status would be helpful.

Is there an easy way to configure the system so that the power button led:

- blinks when the battery is discharging
- glows steadily (as currently) only when fully charged
- (optionally) "breathes" or somesuch when charging

?

Comment: Short answer is “no”. Lenovo controls the LED in the power button via the UEFI, which cannot be reasonably tampered with unless you’re *very* familiar with low-level development. It’s not something that can be safely codified in a step-by-step. That said, my X1 Carbon 5th Gen has an LED on the left side between the two USB-C connectors that glows red when connected to power. This is visible even when the lid is closed. Does your machine not have something similar? 

Comment: If you have to wiggle the connector you have broken hardware as well and should have it looked at.

Comment: @matigo Thanks for the info. Not wed to using power button led. Eg. I remapped capsLock to mouse middle button, so that led is free for use. There does seem to be an led next to the USB connector which I had not noticed but it never seems to light. Perhaps refurb process missed it or maybe it only works when using the lenovo dock connector?

Comment: @David Good point. I'm fairly certain it's the USB connector on the power lead (hardwired into the brick) that is dodgy. I've got a spare brick that came with the refurb so it may be that using that will obviate need for any visible notification.

Comment: @matigo okay, the usb connector led glows orange but apparently only when actually charging (ie. glows if plugged in when battery level is below `tlp`'s "START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0" level; turns off again once "STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0" level reached). So not reliable as an indicator that power is connected.